# How to take values from a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to take value from an `NSMutableDictionary` I can't take it because its multi dimensional

```
{
    "seleted_days" =     (
        TUE,
        WED
    );
    timings =     (
                (
        ),
                (
        ),
                (
                        {
                "close_time" = "05:00 AM";
                "open_time" = "02:00 AM";
                timelist = "02:00 AM , 03:00 AM , 04:00 AM , 05:00 AM";
                timestat = "1,0,0,1";
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                "close_time" = "05:00 AM";
                "open_time" = "02:00 AM";
                timelist = "02:00 AM , 03:00 AM , 04:00 AM , 05:00 AM";
                timestat = "1,0,0,1";
            }
        ),
                (
        ),
                (
        ),
                (
        )
    );
}
```

Need to get open time and close time from this `NSMutableDictionary`

my tried code

```
let array:NSArray =  myretrievedic.value(forKey: "timings") as! NSArray
             for i in 0...array.count
             {

            let subArray:NSArray = array.object(at: i) as! NSArray
            if let dict:NSDictionary = subArray.object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary
            {

            let close_time:String = dict.value(forKey: "close_time") as! String
            let open_time:String = dict.value(forKey: "open_time") as! String


            print(open_time)
            print(close_time)
            }
```

it is crashing when null comes, even if I put if let statements.i don't understand why that if let statements not working

Comment: Please show your tried code, and I think you should avoid using  `NSMutableDictionary` in swift, instead use swift native dictionary type

Answer (score 1):

The value for key `timings` is an array of arrays.

This is a native Swift solution using only Swift native collection types. It includes the line to deserialize the JSON. `data` is the JSON string as `Data` utf8 encoded

```
do {       
    if let root = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
        let timings = root["timings"] as? [[Any]] {
        for timing in timings where !timing.isEmpty {
            if let times = timing.first as? [String:String] {
                let openTime = times["open_time"]!
                let closeTime = times["close_time"]!
                print(openTime, closeTime)
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let dictionary:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    let array:NSArray =  dictionary .value(forKey: "timings") as! NSArray


    for i in 0...array.count
    {
        let subArray:NSArray = array.object(at: 2) as! NSArray

        if subArray.count > 0 {

            let dict:NSMutableDictionary = subArray.object(at: 0) as! NSMutableDictionary

            let close_time:String = dict.value(forKey: "close_time") as! String
            let open_time:String = dict.value(forKey: "open_time") as! String
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to get all the open time and close time